# CustomerManager angularjs by DanWahlin

Tags: angularjs

I m trying to learn Angular.js framework, getting examples on internet "CustomerManager angularjs by DanWahlin" demo seemed comprehensive and downloaded the code from Github "https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager" .

But when I try to open the index.html, it doesn't show anything. am I doing some mistake??
other examples that I downloaded like TODO using angular work fine.

Also if anyone can share some real time examples as to how the code is generally organized in PROD then it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the files are not supposed to be opened in a browser directly from the file-system.
(Many `src`, `href` etc attributes break.)

You have to follow the instructions on the `Readme.md` file. E.g. on Windows:

> The following is required to support the backend services:
>
> - Visual Studio 2012 Web Express (free version) or higher - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products#product-express-summary
> - ASP.NET MVC and Web API are used for the back-end services along with Entity Framework for database access (included if you have VS 2012 express installed)
>
> To get started, double-click the CustomerManager.sln file located at the root of the CustomerManager repository. Once the solution loads press F5 to run the project.